# Using a dash (--) in LaTeX Beamer class

Tags: beamer, punctuation

I want to use a dash in my beamer presentation, however `4--6` looks just like that in the output (i.e. the `--` is not converted to a dash as it usually is).

Does anyone know a way around that?

Here's the requested example (could be it's xelatex...)

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=new,latesthyphen=true,babelshorthands=true]{german}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text,Numbers=OldStyle]{Linux Libertine O}
\setsansfont{Linux Biolinum O}

\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}--\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think it would help if you provide a working minimal example (MWE) that demonstrates the problem. I’ve tested it with my own MWE an can’t see any problem. Maybe your font doesn't work or you have to use something like `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` …

Comment: With a simple test document I couldn't reproduce your problem. Please add a [minimal working example](http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html) illustrating this odd behaviour.

Comment: If you are using xelatex or lualatex: Read the documentation of fontspec (Ligatures=TeX). If not: make a small, complete example.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer Thanks! For some reason I forgot to set my mapping in my sansfont ... I'm still only getting used to xelatex....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\textendash`, such as

```
4\textendash 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{textcmds}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
This is to test dashes \\
X\textendash rays are very powerful
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

If you want to insert dash within beamer slide, use package `textcmds` and include `\textendash` where ever you want to display dash.

If you want to insert a long dash within beamer slide, then use `\textemdash`. Also remember you have to use package `textcmds`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Why `textcmds` is needed? This `\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\textendash 

\textemdash
\end{frame}
\end{document}` works perfectly.